# Java String tab

Tags: java, tabs

when you do a method signature as:

```
public void print(String tab)
```

and you call it as print(""), what is the effect?

Since I have to use:

```
 +tab+
```

to get an actual effect of a tab.

If I call it as :

```
print("\t");
```

would I still need to write +tab+ in the code to cause a tab?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking here.You have a method signature called Print(String tab) If you call this and want to print the contents of tab then you do print("" + tab) to print it out. Please make us aware of what it is you are wanting :) The post is a bit ambiguous :( Jordan

Comment: Not sure what is being asked - is it useful to know that "\t" puts a tab in a string?

Comment: sorry see update please :)

Comment: I still do not follow what you are asking. Not sure what *your* print method is doing. However, normally if you want to print a tab, you use `\t`. For example, `System.out.println("\t")` would print a tab character to stdout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass in string "\t":

```
print("\t")
```